# How to hide a sub level menu from being expanded?

Tags: theming, routes

When a menu is active, drupal displays the sub-menus of the active menu, but because I use the sub-menus in a separate block via the "menu block" module, I don't want the sub-menu to be shown. How can I do it on server side?

Is there an easy drupal way to do it without touching the theme_menu_link? If not, Is there a way to do it in a module rather in template.php? beside, can some one show me how to write the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Add/Edit menu_block options, you can specify the `Maximum depth` of the menu tree to `1`.

Comment: So you actually suggest to use menu_block also for the main menu. good idea

Comment: Yup. It makes working with menus easier.